# Can't handle promise rejection

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function sendPushNotification(subscription, urlEncodedData){
  try {
    webpush.sendNotification(subscription, urlEncodedData);
  } catch (err){
    console.log('err');
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

This doesn't catch the error, it is still considered an 'unhandledRejection'. Why?

Comment: Wouldn't you have to `await` it or something? Any other details on webpush?

Answer (score 2):

If you're calling an `async` function, or a function that returns a `Promise` then you need to sequence things properly:

```js
async function sendPushNotification(subscription, urlEncodedData){
  try {
    await webpush.sendNotification(subscription, urlEncodedData);
  } catch (err){
    console.log('err');
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Here `await` will capture any response. An error condition that will manifest as an exception.

Note that this makes `sendPushNotification()` return a `Promise` so you will have to treat it as asynchronous. This means the caller needs to `await` as well, and that may have impacts up the call chain depending on your sequencing requirements.

Comment: Brutal, thanks for the help I would have never figured it out.

Comment: Wrapping your head around JavaScript asynchronous coding style can be a bit of a trip if you're used to blocking code (synchronous) like in most other languages, so don't beat yourself up about it. You were really close.

Comment: I usually work with async/await in JS but I've not seen this before.